# PrimeFaces dialog doesn't use the information I provide in the view

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

I have a view which contain the following fields:

```
<p:selectOneMenu style="width:40px" value="#{capacityFamilyBean.capacityFamily.bottleneck}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{capacityFamilyBean.availableCapFamilyBottlenecks()}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:inputText id="capacityFamilyName" binding="#{capacityFamilyName}" style="margin-left:20px" value="#{capacityFamilyBean.capacityFamily.name}">
    <p:ajax event="change" update="newBundleButton"/>
</p:inputText>

<p:commandButton id="newBundleButton" icon="ui-icon-plus" disabled="#{empty capacityFamilyName.value}" value="${msgs.New}" oncomplete="PF('capacityFamilyDialog').show();"/>
```

you can see the value properties are `{capacityFamilyBean.capacityFamily.prprty}`

`capacityFamilyDialog` uses the same properties, but they are not pre-filled

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{capacityFamilyBean.capacityFamily.bottleneck}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{capacityFamilyBean.availableCapFamilyBottlenecks()}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:inputText id="capacityFamilyName" style="margin-left:20px" value="#{capacityFamilyBean.capacityFamily.name}"/>
```

I'm assuming they refer to different capacityFamily object, but how can I counter that?

Comment: What is the scope of `capacityFamilyBean`?  Is everything in the same view?  A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help a lot.

Comment: Try to update `capacityFamilyName` on ajax `change` event.

Comment: @ForguesR it's CDI ViewScoped. I tried SessionScoped but it has the same result. The view is the same although the dialog is in another file included with <ui:include>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog is delivered with the page. So it's completely empty.

```
oncomplete="PF('capacityFamilyDialog').show();"
```

is pure javascript and only shows this empty popup. If you like to have a dialog with actual values, you have to `update` it in an ajax-call like your `commandButton`.

```
<p:commandButton value="${msgs.New}" update="capacityFamilyDialog_ID" oncomplete="PF('capacityFamilyDialog').show();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dialogue is functional when you click the button. I think you should update the id for dialogue box.

JSF Code

```
 <p:commandButton id="impBtb"
     process="@this" icon="ui-icon-plus" disabled="#{empty capacityFamilyName.value}" 
      value="${msgs.New}" oncomplete="PF('capacityFamilyDialog').show();" update="@form:capacityFamilyDialog">
</p:commandButton>
```

So, you may have to perform a ajax-call from your commandbutton to update the dialog box.

Hope it helps!!